# React hot loader does not update page upon saving changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I am starting a React project with webpack and trying to get hot loading to work. The console output says `App updated`, but it doesn't show the saved changes (which is simply text between the `div` tags in `App.js`).

For example, I'd change `Hey sup` to `Hey sup dude`, but the text in the browser page stays as `Hey sup`, despite the console saying that the `App is up to date.` I can see the change when I manually refresh the page though.

I've tried following along with [this React boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/), but am unable to get the page to show the saved changes.

[image: Console output after saving changes.]

### client/App.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hey sup
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: [
            'env',
            'react'
          ],
          plugins: [
            'react-hot-loader/babel'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

### client/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import App from './App';
import './style.css';

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render(App);

// Webpack Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    render(App);
  });
}
```

### public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? Please add it or select on of the answers as I am having the same issue.

Comment: I'm also facing same problem, If anyone finds solution please help me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the preset to `latest` instead of `env` works.

```
[
  "latest", {
    "es2015": {
      "modules": false
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the entry section of your webpack configuration you need to add this line:

```
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000'
```

as a result you'll have something like this:

```
entry: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './client/index.js'
]
```

[Here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-webpack-boilerplate) I have some code with that feature. Hope it results helpful to you.